# Plesk Presence builder not showing website

Tags: plesk

Currently having an issue with a client. The website they built using the Plesk Presence builder is no longer editable when they click in the builder. It instead show the new website page. No changes that I  or the client no of have been made to the account and the website it's self is still live and unaffected. Is there anyway to manually ensure the website and the builder are connect within the Plesk server?I have complete access to the Plesk server in question so I can make any necessary changes.

Any advise would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, Plesk knowledge base article which was rather hard to dig up on it : https://kb.plesk.com/en/114532 . the article is for Linux/Unix based Plesk but the idea is the same for windows.